# Safe to change field in large database (table structure)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just noticed that I have `smallInt` on a field, that should've been just `int`. Is it safe just to change it? What will happen to all the data in that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to change the smaller value to a larger value without worrying about any data truncation or other issues.

If it were the other way around, you would have to worry about any data value maximums while moving to the smaller data-type.